# Dynamic MongoDB collection in spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to create a MongoDB collection for each month dynamically.
Example: viewLog_01_2018, viewLog_02_2018

```
@Document(collection = "#{viewLogRepositoryImpl.getCollectionName()}")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(def = "{'viewer':1, 'viewed':1}", name = "viewerViewedIndex",unique=true)
})
public class ViewLog {

    private Integer viewer;
    private Integer viewed;
    private Date time;

    public Integer getViewer() {
        return viewer;
    }
    public void setViewer(Integer viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }
    public Integer getViewed() {
        return viewed;
    }
    public void setViewed(Integer viewed) {
        this.viewed = viewed;
    }
    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

The implementation for the collection name is as follows:

```
@Repository
public class ViewLogRepositoryImpl implements ViewLogRepositoryCustom {

    private String collectionName;

    public ViewLogRepositoryImpl() {
        CommonUtility common = new CommonUtility();
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = common.getStartingEndingDateOfMonth();
        setCollectionName("viewLog_"+pair.getFirst()+"_"+pair.getSecond());
    }

    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        return collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
    }

}
```

On my each request, to save a document, I am setting the collection name as:

```
@Autowired
    ViewLogRepository viewLogRepository;

    public boolean createLog(int viewer, int viewed,String viewed_mmm, Date time){
        CommonUtility common = new CommonUtility();
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = common.getStartingEndingDateOfMonth();
        viewLogRepository.setCollectionName("viewLog_"+pair.getFirst()+"_"+pair.getSecond());
        ViewLog viewLog = new ViewLog();
        viewLog.setViewer(viewer);
        viewLog.setViewed(viewed);
        viewLog.setTime(time);                  
        ViewLog viewLog2 = viewLogRepository.save(viewLog);
        return true;
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that I when for the first time I up my service the mongo collection that is created has the unique attribute for the fields 'viewer' and 'viewed' but for any subsequent collection that is created dynamically, the document does not have the unique constraint and multiple entries of same viewer-viewed combination are able to be inserted.

Any help will be very much appreciated.